# Java output the number of scores above or equal to the average

Tags: java

So I have class assignment where I have to let users type values into an array, get the average and output the number of scores above or equal to the average, and the number of scores below the average.

However, I only figured out average part.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter size of your array: ");

    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int a[] = new int[n];
    System.out.println("Enter the test scores");

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = sc.nextInt(); 
    }

    int sum = 0;

    for(int b=0; b < a.length; b++) {
        sum = sum + a[b]; 
    }

    double average = ((double)sum) / a.length;
    System.out.println("The average is"+" " + average);
}
```

I would like to get help on the part where I output the number of scores that is above or equal to the average and number of scores below the average.

Comment: Add a simply boolean expression. If `scores > average`...

Comment: you can do it in a second similar loop with `if (a[b] >= average)`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter size of your array: ");

int n = sc.nextInt();

int a[] = new int[n];

System.out.println("Enter the test scores");

for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{

  a[i] = sc.nextInt(); 

}
   int sum = 0;

        for(int b=0; b < a.length; b++){

            sum = sum + a[b]; 
        }
         double average = ((double)sum) / a.length;

       int above = 0;
       int below = 0;

       for(int b=0; b < a.length; b++){

            if ((double)a[b] > average) {
                above++;
            }
            else if ((double)a[b] < average) {
                below++;
            }
        }


        System.out.println("The average is"+" " + average);
        System.out.println("The count of numbers above average is " + above);
        System.out.println("The count of number equal to average is " + (a.length - below - above));
        System.out.println("The count of numbers below average is " + below);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to output each score above the average, then put your System.out line in another for loop, iterating over the array, comparing each element to the average.

Example

```
System.out.print("Scores Above or Equal to the Average: ");
for(int i = 0, i < array.length, i++) {
    if (array[i] >= average) {
        System.out.print(array[i] + ", ");
    } else {}
}
```

If your are trying to get the number of scores above or equal to the average, essentially do the same thing but add a counter variable

Example

```
int scoresAbove = 0;
for(int i = 0, i < array.length, i++) {
    if (array[i] >= average) {
        scoresAbove ++;
    } else {}
}
System.out.print("Number of Scores Above the Average: " + scoresAbove);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a code block like this:

```js
int numScoresAbove = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<a.length(); i++){
  if(a[i]>=average){
    numScoresAbove++
    }
}
System.out.println("Number of scores above or equal to the average: "+numScoresAbove);
```

Then use pretty much the same thing for the less than part of it.

Comment: Did this solve your question? If it did, then click the button that says "this solved my question" or best answer, then others can find this easier if they have a similar question.